# Get the next immediate Time from a list of date time in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have a list of `DateTime` =

```
[
  2021-08-17 11:00:00.000000,
  2021-08-17 11:30:00.000000,
  2021-08-17 12:00:00.000000,
  2021-08-17 12:30:00.000000,
  2021-08-17 13:00:00.000000,
]
```

How can I find the immediate next **TIME** using `DateTime.now()`?

**ONLY TIME**.

If `DateTime.now()` returns `2021-08-17 11:25:00.000000` I need to return 5 minutes

**CONTEXT: **

My application needs to save the DateTime for another work so I cannot just save the Time. The above mentioned list of DateTimes is saved under the title: `Sunday`. Checking if today is Sunday or not is quite easy but I need some sort of mechanism for getting the difference with next datetime but I only need the Time difference and not the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `List<DateTime>` is sorted in order of earliest to latest, a straightforward, brute-force approach is to just iterate over your `List<DateTime>` and stop when you find one that is at or after the specified `DateTime`:

```dart
/// Returns the [Duration] to the next [DateTime] from [validTimes] that occurs at
/// or after [now].
///
/// Returns `null` if there is no [DateTime] at or after [now].
///
/// [validTimes] must be already sorted in order of earliest to latest.
Duration? timeToNext(List<DateTime> validTimes, DateTime now) {
  for (var time in validTimes) {
    if (time.compareTo(now) >= 0) {
      return time.difference(now);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

void main() {
  var times = [
    DateTime(2021, 08, 17, 11, 00),
    DateTime(2021, 08, 17, 11, 30),
    DateTime(2021, 08, 17, 12, 00),
    DateTime(2021, 08, 17, 12, 30),
    DateTime(2021, 08, 17, 13, 00),
  ];

  var now = DateTime(2021, 08, 17, 11, 25);
  var duration = timeToNext(times, now);
  print(duration); // Prints: 0:05:00.000000
}
```

If your `List<DateTime>` is very large, then you could use [`lowerBound`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/lowerBound.html) from `package:collection`:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

Duration? timeToNext(List<DateTime> validTimes, DateTime now) {
  var i = lowerBound(validTimes, now);
  if (i == validTimes.length) {
    return null;
  }
  return validTimes[i].difference(now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,
the difference between DateTimes is pretty easy using difference method for the DateTime class look that in action:

```
int returnDiference(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2) {
  final int diference = dateTime1.difference(dateTime2).inSeconds;
  return diference;
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIgeJ.png)

I hope that will be useful for you.

Comment: I need the next immediate time and find the difference between `DateTime.now()` and next immediate time.